# Get count of departmant with total employees for period of month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have requirement to get count of distinct department with total employees in  period of month but unfortunately query is not working and throwing error

My table

```
Department_id emloyee_id   date_time

  1             1          2020-02-01
  1             2          2020-02-04 
  3             7          2020-02-06
  1             4          2020-02-07
```

expected output

```
total department=2
total employee of all department=4
```

But all should work based on last one record , I am getting sql syntax error

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department_id) x, COUNT(*) y 
  FROM department 
 WHERE date_time>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') 
   AND date_time<DATE(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY and status='1'
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department_id) x, COUNT(*) y FROM department

Comment: @Strawberry  I am getting error because of where condition kept to check one month record.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated my query as  you suggested still getting error can you please  check this updated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should use month instead of day and are missing a bracket after month

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department_id) AS departments,
       COUNT(*) AS employees
FROM department
WHERE date_time>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
AND date_time < DATE(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND status = '1';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them within only one query :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Department_id), COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id)
  FROM department  
 WHERE date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND status = '1';
```

counting both distinctly.

**Update :** If you mean to stay within the *current month*, then also

`AND date_time>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')`

might be added to this query as in your original one.

Comment: This won't give OP their desired result as employee 1 works for 2 different departments.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan i don't want distinct eon employee and by mistake I have added employee_id =1 in both department actually department id=3 have employee id=7